# Angular - pipe function break execution flow

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have below code:

```
 subscriber.pipe(
       switchMap(data => {
          this.getData().pipe(
             map(() => res),
             catchError(error => {
                 return of(null);
             })
          );
       }),
       switchMap(data => {
    
       })
    
    ).subscribe();
```

In case of error in first switchMap i am returning of(null) so next switchMap is reciving data as null.
But i like to stop the execution in case first switchMap goes to catchError block, it should not execute second switchMap. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: _Don't_ catch the error?

Comment: I also needed to display a error message i missed in the code snippet, i added catchError block at the end like Tobias suggested.

Comment: In the example you weren't using `error`, note you can also use `throwError` if you actually have something to do in the `catchError` but want the overall result to be unchanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `catchError` at the end of the pipe.

```
subscriber.pipe(
   switchMap(data => {
       ...
   }),
   switchMap(data => {
       ...
   }),
   catchError(error => {
       return of(null);
   })
).subscribe(val => {
    // val will be null if any error happened
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use filter here. from catch error you can return null and after the first switchMap you can use a filter to filter out null.

```
subscriber.pipe(
       switchMap(data => {
          this.getData().pipe(
             map(() => res),
             catchError(error => {
                 return null;
             })
          );
       }),
       filter(v => v),
       switchMap(data => {
    
       })
    
    ).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

## RxJS # EMPTY

EMPTY is an observable that emits nothing and completes immediately.

```ts
subscriber.pipe(
       switchMap(data => {
          this.getData().pipe(
             map(() => res),
             catchError(_ => EMPTY)
          );
       }),
       switchMap(data => {
    
       })
    
    ).subscribe();
```